How to Configure Nginx Ingress Controller Custom Port to route traffic to Java Spring Backend in Kubernetes?
I am using NGINX Ingress Controller and create a custom-port 8080. But when i create ingress it still point to 80 port. How to fix this ?
My custom port for nginx ingress:
 ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  - name: server-port
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP

frontend-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: main-application
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: jobseeker.devnoneknow.online
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 80

frontend-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  namespace: main-application
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: frontend
  type: ClusterIP

backend-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: server-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/port: "8080"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: api.devnoneknow.online
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 8080

backend-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: main-application
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP

i try to add this annotations in my backend-ingress.yaml:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/port: "8080"

